# Symfony 2.8 - no puede renderizar ruta denominada "_assetic_c49beaa_0"

Tags: symfony2, symfony

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto symfony 2.8, tenia el proyecto versionado con **svn** pero ahora lo estamos empezando a trabajar con **git**

Al sincronizar mi repositorio local con la nube, e intentar ejecutarlo me genero el siguiente error

*An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Unable to generate a URL for the named route "_assetic_c49beaa_0" as such route does not exist.").*

¿Sera que me falta instalar algun vendor¿? o alguna configutacion me falta?¿

Cualquier orientaciòn es bienvenida!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo pude resolver corriendo los siguientes comandos sobre el proyecto

```
php app/console assets:install web --symlink
php app/console assets:install web
```

Y no olvidar de limpiar la cache!!!!